# Want to write/read data to/from json file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html, file

I want to write data to a json file (which is supposed to be created by me).

There is no any limit to the entries allowed in this file. Additionally, I want to read the same data from that file & to show it on one HTML page, from where I will have to collect data.

I am new to jQuery. Some help would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Is this being served by a server or directly from a ```file://``` url?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Is it any particular sort of data?

Comment: {
"name": "Zara Ali",
"age" : "67",
"sex": "female"
} this data we need to append in file every time. first time we need to create file on local storage. next time i need to append same json data and on show button i need to read data and parse it and show into HTML in table format.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you on your way but please note that this is not an out the box solution:

You first will need to create a php file which will read/write the json file let's say 'post_item.php':

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$file = file_get_contents("your-file.json", true);

        $data = json_decode($file, true);
        unset($file);


        //the data you will write, which is coming from the ajax request
        $data[] = array(
                            'id' => uniqid(),
                            'title' => $title,
                            'description' => $description

                        );

        $result = json_encode($data);
        //echo $result;

        file_put_contents("your-file.json", true, $result);

        $result = 'Success';
        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {

        $result = 'Error';
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

You will need the HTML form in order to gather and post the data:

```
.....
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newTitle">Title: </label>
    <input id="title" name="titel" type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description: </label>
    <textarea id="description" name="kort_omschrijving"  class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
.....
```

You can than post the data with an ajax call that you must trigger (e.g. with an Click event:

```
 var title = $('#title').val(),
            description = $('description').val()

        var postData = {
            title:  title,
            description:  description

        };


            $.ajax({
                url: 'post_item.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postData,
            })
            .done(function(result) {

                if(result == 'Success'){

                   alert('Item succesfully added')

                }else{
                    alert('Could not add the item')
                }

            })
```

This will post the data in your json file, you will need an other php file and an other ajax call in order to read the file!! If you succeed to implement this and write the file to the json, I will help you with the following step